# Adding Constraints Makes Button Disappear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

New to programming, so forgive me if this is a beginner question.

I have a custom button class (DropDownPicker) that I initialize based on the constraints of a placeholder UIButton that I create in storyboard. In other words, I create a placeholder in storyboard, make it an outlet, and then initialize my custom button to have the same constraints.

In the view controller's ViewDidLoad I have this:

```
let button = DropDownPicker.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

self.view.addSubview(button)

button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.topAnchor).isActive = true
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: placeholder.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

And in the DropDownPicker class I have:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    layer.cornerRadius = 15
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    clipsToBounds = true
}
```

The weird thing is, if I create the placeholder in an empty view controller without any constraints, it works. But if I add constraints, it disappears. Any ideas why this might be?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a placeholder?  Why not have the DropDownPicker button directly in the storyboard?

Comment: Give the button a size. Meaning, set `width` and `height` to something other than `0`.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do that. I do have the button set to my DropDownPicker class, but from what I can tell it still needs to be initialized from the view controller. Again I apologize for the super basic question.

Comment: @Don I tried that but no luck.

Comment: That's OK, you should be doing it like @UpholderOfTruth mentioned. In your `init` above, remove your setup code and place it in a new method called `setup()` or something. You will also need to add `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}`. Call `super` and your new `setup()` method from inside that `init` as well. This is the `init` the storyboard uses. Since you're already setting the class in the identity inspector, you should be good to go.

Comment: In the view controller, I removed `let button = DropDownPicker.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))` and `self.view.addSubview(button)` and the placeholder constraints code from my viewDidLoad. In the class, I moved the setup code to `setup()` and called `setup()` in `override init(frame: CGRect)` and `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.  Did I miss something? It still seems to come up blank in simulator.

Comment: Nevermind! Think I had the outlet connected wrong. Works perfectly now, thanks so much to both of you!